# Amazon Cloud, storing assets

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am creating a web app for some co-working. I have text with assets (most of them pictures in print quality, say 5MB, all in all about 5GB per month).

I am going to host this on amazon's cloud using EC2 instances for a node.js server and a mongodb with attached block storage.

The assets are private to an object so not everyone will have access to it.

How should i handle the assets? Save them as binarys in the database or load them up to S3? (or any other amazon service)

Does somebody have experience on this? Or maybe some helpful links. Thanks in advance

Comment: You could use GridFS in MongoDB -- but I'm not sure given the amount of data you're talking about and the growth pattern that it would make long term sense. It might make for very expensive hosting. Have you looked into hosting costs, etc?

Comment: i guess in my case (Europe) it is cheaper to save the stuff to S3 or CloudFront (i dont know if i can restrict access to cloudfront files, and it seems to me this is for large files) because block storage is more expansive than S3 storage espacially when the volume grows

Comment: Cloudfront is quite expensive but S3 in reduced redundancy setting is really cheap about half the price of normal S3 storage, same speed just a little less redundancy in their data center.

Comment: Many companies rely on complex random generation of exposed file names so that they are essentially impossible to guess. THen, they can host it in more traditional (& less expensive) ways. There's no additional security in this mode.

Comment: this is a legal problem for me because if anyone leaks the name the file is exposed to the public which is not suitable here

Comment: You know S3 can handle private files right? So you can make a file on S3 private to your app which means everyone must go through your application to get the file. That is the way that sites such as instagram etc solve this problem

Comment: Added to that, when you try and get a youtube video directly from their direct url that leads to their cdn that is also when you get a permission problem error response, they force you to go through their python servers to get to their videos

Comment: @Sammaye I know that i can handle private files on s3 this is because i would even consider it, it was only as answer to WiredPrairie.

Comment: @pfried Oh ok yea I looked at your question too and realised I was a little premature :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably store the assets on S3 without public access, then you can grant access to authorized users by generating temporal signed urls from your webservers when needed.
This way you can leverage your servers complexity by handing over the storage dirty work to S3, and you can still have your files accessed only by who has access to them.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do access control there are lots of things you could do but the most obvious would be to server the asserts through your web server and have it implement the access control logic desired.  Your app could proxy through the source object from S3 or MongoDB GridFS.  If you are already using MongoDB, in this particular case I would use GridFS unless you want some of the cost saving features of S3 such as reduced redundancy storage.